# as3 xml Slideshow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Below is the code of my slideshow, the problem I am having is that after 1st image that loads has the perfect size which I needs but the second image loads has different size I want it to be of same size as of 1st one. Also the images are not loading in a sequence. Can any expert figure out and solve the problem.

```
stop();
import gs.*;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

//hides the description box until the image is loaded
//hides the image until it is loaded

theImage.alpha=0;
loadingBar.visible = false;

//variables to hold the final coordinates of the image tween
var finalX:Number;
var finalY:Number;

//variable to hold the number of images in the XML
var listLength:Number;

//keeps track of what image should be displayed
var currPainting:Number=0;

//arrays to hold the contents of the XML, using this to allow
//for the random order of the images
var imageArray:Array = new Array();


//Loader event for the XML
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

var xml:XML;

loader.load(new URLRequest("paintings.xml"));

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
//load XML
xml=new XML(e.target.data);
var il:XMLList=xml.images;
listLength=il.length();

populateArray();
}

function populateArray():void {
//takes the properties defined in the XML and stores them 
//into arrays
var i:Number;
for (i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    imageArray[i]=xml.images[i].pic;

}
beginImage();
}

function beginImage():void {
//grabs a random number between 0 and the number
//of images in the array
currPainting=Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length);

//load description

var imageLoader = new Loader();

//catches errors if the loader cannot find the URL path
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, catchFunction);
//actually loads the URL defined in the image array
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageArray[currPainting]));
//adds a listener for while the image is loading
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imgLoading);
//adds a listener for what to do when the image is done loading
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgLoaded);


function catchFunction(e:IOErrorEvent) {
    trace("Bad URL: " + imageArray[currPainting] + " does not exist");
    //take out the bad URL from the array
    imageArray.splice(currPainting,1);


    //check to see if there are images left,
    //else restart the slideshow
    if (imageArray.length==0) {
        populateArray();
    } else {
        beginImage();
    }
}

function imgLoading(event:ProgressEvent):void{
    //show the loading bar, and update the width
    //based on how much is loaded
    loadingBar.visible = true;
    loadingBar.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
    loadingBar.y = stage.stageHeight/3
    loadingBar.bar.width = (event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal)*100;
}

function imgLoaded(event:Event):void {
    loadingBar.visible = false;
    var scale:Number =  stage.stageWidth * 0.292708 / theImage.width;
    //add the image and get the dimensions to center the image
    theImage.addChild(imageLoader);
    theImage.x = stage.stageWidth/2.85;
    theImage.y = 0;

    if(theImage.height * scale > stage.stageHeight){
    scale = stage.stageHeight * 0.704918 / theImage.height;
    }   

    // apply the scale to the image
    theImage.scaleX = theImage.scaleY = scale;


    //take the contents of the loaded image and cast it as bitmap data
    //to allow for bitmap smoothing

    var image:Bitmap = imageLoader.content as Bitmap;
    image.smoothing=true;
            //start tween function
    easeIn();
}
}

function easeIn():void {

TweenLite.to(theImage, 8, {onComplete:hideStuff});
TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:1, overwrite:0});
}

function hideStuff():void {
TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, {alpha:0, onComplete:nextImage});

}


function nextImage():void {
//take out the image that was just displayed
imageArray.splice(currPainting,1);


//remove the picture
theImage.removeChildAt(0);

//start over
if (imageArray.length==0) {
    populateArray();
} else {
    beginImage();
}
}
```

Here is the xml

```
    <xml>
            <images><pic>portfolio1.jpg</pic></images>
            <images><pic>portfolio2.jpg</pic></images>
            <images><pic>portfolio3.jpg</pic></images>
            <images><pic>portfolio4.jpg</pic></images>
            <images><pic>portfolio5.jpg</pic></images>

    </xml>
```

Comment: why dont you make the images all the same size outside of flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `theImage`'s height represents image height after loading. That should be available with loader. To accommodate for different sized images, you'd have to bring actual height/width of image while applying scale. Else, of course, you can pre-resize all the images to same size.

About random loading, that's exactly what

```
currPainting=Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length);
```

in `beginImage` is doing. To have the loading done in order, you can pick up 0th element directly.